# Creating new entities while enabling injection

Tags: jpa, ejb, java-ee-6, cdi

I have a method on a stateless session bean which creates a new instance of an entity and persists it. You might normally use new MyEntity() to create the object but I would like injection to populate some of the properties of the entity for me.

I got partial success using

```
@Inject 
@New 
private MyEntity myNewEntity;
```

in the session bean and then using that instance in my method.

The problem I have now is that the second time the method is called, myNewEntity isn't a new object, its the same object as the one created the first time. As a result I'm getting

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '9' for key 'PRIMARY'

Or at least that's why I think I'm getting this exception. Certainly if I use new MyEntity() I don't get the exception but my injection doesn't happen.

Am I on the wrong track? How can I create a new local entity object while enabling injection?

Any help would be great!

Comment: What is the primary key of the object and what is your injection framework defining as default values for those fields?

Comment: My primary key is an auto generated id i.e.
  @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = AUTO)
 private long   id; I have a working solution now see below, not sure if this is 'right'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all - I have serious doubts that it's a good idea to use CDI to control the lifecycle of a Entity. See this quote from the documentation ([here](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/1.1.0.Final/en-US/html/beanscdi.html#d0e799)):

> According to this definition, JPA
>   entities are technically managed
>   beans. However, entities have their
>   own special lifecycle, state and
>   identity model and are usually
>   instantiated by JPA or using new.
>   Therefore we don't recommend directly
>   injecting an entity class. We
>   especially recommend against assigning
>   a scope other than @Dependent to an
>   entity class, since JPA is not able to
>   persist injected CDI proxies.

What you should do to create new instances of entities is adding a layer of indirection, either with `@Produces` or `@Unwraps` (Seam Solder, if you need it to be truly stateless), and thereby making sure that you code explicitly calls `new`.

Comment: Is a @Produces method that calls new with the default constructor different from the default behaviour without an @Produces method?

Comment: Caution: The quotation above is not from the official EE specs but from the JBoss Weld docs, there might be difference in other implementations.

Comment: To come back on this I found Jan's advise to be right. I used a different approach http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7830347/transparently-recording-the-last-modified-user-on-jpa-entity

Answer (score 0):

I think I have a working solution now which seems okay, though I'm not quite sure why it works so I welcome your feedback on a better solution. I am now injecting a DAO-style bean into my stateless session bean:

```
@Stateless
public class PhoneService {

    @Inject
    protected ProblemReports problemReports;
```

An injecting my entity into the ProblemReports bean:

```
public class ProblemReports {

    @Inject
    @New
    private ProblemReport newProblemReport;
```

I assume that ProblemReports defaults to @Dependant scope which as I understand it should be the same as the stateless session bean which containts it. I could understand this if the scope of ProblemReports was shorter, causing a new instance of ProblemReport to be created when the new ProblemReports is created; but it isn't.

Is this just an example of EJB and CDI not playing well together?

Comment: If ProblemReport is an entity, then this solution is a problem itself ;-). You definitely do not want any entities to be created as managed beans. See my answer below.